# How to set first option as default option

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular4-forms

I have worked on angular 4 project.
In this project, I have a requirement to set the first option as default option in select list.
But problem is that this select box is under a child component and data from this select box is build passed from parent component.
For better understanding the code is as follow:

parent component html :

```
<serviceSelect [services]="services"></serviceSelect>
```

child component html:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedServiceType" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ngModelChange)="getServiceType($event)">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let service of settings?.service_type">
       <option [ngValue]="service">{{service.name}}</option>
   </ng-container>
</select>
```

child component .ts code:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
   selector: 'serviceSelect',
   templateUrl: './serviceSelect.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./serviceSelect.component.scss']
})
export class serviceSelectComponent {
      @Input() services : any;
      selectedServiceType: any;

      getServiceType(event) {
        this.selectedServiceType = event;
      }
}
```

We do not have access to services variable in `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`.
I have tried to set default value through these functions. If any other suggestion how to first option as default let me know.

Comment: in typescript set this.selectedServiceType = this.settings.service_type[0];

Comment: we haven't access of services variable in .ts file. Thats the problem am asking for

Comment: Use setter for `@Input` or `ngOnChanges` hook

Comment: @yurzui Can you please explain it

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqnb3j?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts Example of setter

Comment: thanks @yurzui , Its really working for me : )

Comment: `ngOnChanges` should work too

Comment: can you please move your comment into answer, so I marked it as accepted.